# How to recursively iterate over a list with Maybe objects in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, recursion, option-type

I am trying to create a function `justifyList` that takes a list of `Maybe` objects (`[Maybe a]`) and return a list of all objects of `Just` type, discarding any element that is `Nothing` in the parameter list.

My solution for now is

```
justifyList :: [Maybe a] -> [a]
justifyList [] = []
justifyList (x:xs) 
    | (isNothing x) = justifyList xs
    | otherwise = x : justifyList xs
```

where I try to recursively iterate through the parameter list and recursively put the current element `x` to the returned list `[a]`, if it is of `Just` type.

However when interpreting a type mismatch error is generated

> Couldn't match type a with Maybe a

Hence my question is; how do I recursively iterate through a list of `Maybe` objects? If this solution is sufficient, how do I convert `xs` to be of `Maybe` type?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Such function already lives in the [**`Data.Maybe`** module](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html) and is named [**`catMaybes :: [Maybe a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:catMaybes).

You can implement this with recursion, but it might be more elegant to do this with *list comprehension*, since this allows us to effectively pattern match and unwrap at the same time, so:

```
justifyList :: [Maybe a] -> [a]
justifyList xs = [ x | Just x <- xs ]
```

only for items that satisfy the `Just x` pattern, it will yield an item, so `Just x <- xs` performs a filtering as well.

Answer (score 7):

Pattern-match on the `Maybe`s

```
justifyList :: [Maybe a] -> [a]
justifyList [] = []
justifyList (Nothing:xs) = justifyList xs
justifyList (Just x:xs) = x : justifyList xs
```

Answer (score 3):

In the line `justifyList (x:xs)` `x` is of type `Maybe a` then in the line `| otherwise = x : justifyList xs` you try to add `x::Maybe a` to a list of `a`.

You need to break open the `Maybe` type using pattern matching so you can get the actual value inside. (I am going to use an explicit `case` statement because it makes the logic easier but best practice is to use pattern matching in the function itself - left as an exercise to the reader).

```
justifyList (x:xs) = case x of
  Nothing -> justifyList xs
  Just a  -> a:justifyList xs
```

As a general rule only use a guard pattern (`| = ...`) when you need to makes some test like a comparison or function evaluation. When all you need to is some information about the type (which is much of the time in practice) use pattern matching or case statements instead.

---

For those who may find this in a search I will add one last bit there is a function [`catMaybes`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:catMaybes) in Data.Maybe which does exactly this operation already.

Answer (score 1):

If the first element of the list is `Nothing`, apply `id` to the recursive result. If it is `Just x`, apply `(x:)` to the recursive result. Use `maybe` to select the correct function.

```
justifyList [] = []
justifyList (x:xs) = (maybe id (:) x) (justifyList xs)
```

- `maybe id (:) Nothing == id`
- `maybe id (:) (Just x) == (x:)`.